# How can I use "Propose Tag wiki" without taking the risk of a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

A few things happened to me the past few days, while submitting suggested edits of wiki tags and/or wiki excerpts, for **existing** tags (for which I do **not** have the **privilege** to create them; at best I can only "suggest" such tags to be created):

- [Rejected tag wiki edit for **aliases**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52773), a tag that got deleted AFTER I submitted my suggestion.
- [Rejected tag wiki excerpt edit for **aliases**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52773), a tag that got deleted AFTER I submitted my suggestion.
- [Rejected tag wiki edit for **charts.module**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52667), a tag that got deleted AFTER I submitted my suggestion, and after 1 approve followed by 1 reject of that suggested edit was performed. So the actual review process for that specific suggested edit seems like interrupted, since a final reviewer probably never got a chance to look at that suggested edit.
- [Rejected tag wiki edit for **remote**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52579) and [Rejected tag wiki excerpt edit for **remote**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52580), a tag that got deleted AFTER I submitted my suggestion, and after 1 approve was given. So the actual review process for that specific suggested edit seems like either interrupted or still waiting additional reviews.

For the sake of understanding: I do not question in any way the specific reviewers, or their reasons for rejection (I do consider all of them as reviewers that I respect). So let that not be the reason for any potential (anoymous?) downvotes of **[this question](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/how-can-i-use-propose-tag-wiki-without-taking-the-risk-of-a-rejected-edit)** please, or **[my own answer](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/how-can-i-use-propose-tag-wiki-without-taking-the-risk-of-a-rejected-edit/3203#3203)** I added to it (if you've other reasons to downvote: no problem).

However, **something seems broken in the review process of suggested edits for wiki tags and / or excerpts**. Why do "I" get a "rejected edit" for each of these events described above?

To phrase it another way:

- "I" invest time in researching wiki tags that seem to be in use (at least 1 question had these tags, some had multiple questions tagged with it).
- "I" invest time to submit the suggested edit.
- That suggestion seems to trigger something at 1 or more reviewers like "oeps, that tag should not be there".
- And instead of "me" being rewarded for what I suggested, I get punished by a rejected edit.

To further proof my point, please consider **existing tag**[password-reset](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password-reset), which:

- has **[1 question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153521/user-password-reset-without-sending-an-email)** (only!) that is using the tag.
- the actual question was asked by ... one of the reviewers involved in one of the reviews mentioned above.
- for which **[NO tag wiki or wiki excerpt exists](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1939)**.

**My question**: what are "my" options to contribute to this specific tag wiki / excerpt, without taking the risk of another rejected edit?

Comment: Tag wiki edits are dangerous. They  often get rejected, and sometimes for non-obvious reasons.  I've simply stopped doing tag wiki edits. They are simply too often and too easily rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested edits for wikis relative to tags that are removed from all questions using them, or to tags that get merged, are automatically removed from the review queue simply for the fact it doesn't make sense to review a suggested edit for a tag wiki that is then removed. I assume they are automatically rejected on the assumption that suggesting an edit for a tag that should not be used would not be an action users should take (i.e., it was a not necessary/correct action).

As for the rejected edits you are taking as examples:

- *aliases* was never used for Drush aliases only; I found questions using it for different purposes, including domain aliases.
- There is no consensus about using *charts.module* when there is already *charts*.
- *password-reset* was used only by a question asked from a user who also self-answered his question, well knowing he was going to suggest a specific module, for which the tag was created. A tag is used for the question, not because an answer mentions a specific module.

As general guideline:

- Don't suggest a tag wiki edit for tags that aren't used from at least 10 questions. A single question using the tag doesn't preserve the tag from the automatic deletion, nor it is enough to be sure there is a consensus about using the tag or how the tag should be used.
- Before suggesting a tag wiki edit, be sure you understand the meaning given to the tag from the users who use it. In the case the tag has too many meanings, it is probable the tag needs to be removed or replace by two or more tags.

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution (answer) is like so:

1) At a minimum:

- do NOT allow tags to be deleted while a review process of a suggested edit for the tag wiki or wiki tag excerpt is ongoing.
- if a tag gets deleted after the review process completed, then do NOT consider that as a rejected edit for the user who suggested an edit to it.

2) Ideally also:

- find a way to compensate the user who triggered a review process of a tag that turned out to be obsolete (or something like that).
- add an extra option to "flag a tag as potentially candidate for deletion" (similar to flagging a comment for moderation).

3) If perfect is not good enough:

Do not allow tags to be deleted, for as long as there is at least 1 other tag wiki or excerpt that still references it. That would have avoided that I needed to submit these 2 extra edits for the [drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drush), edit I've suggested after the above mentioned tags got deleted:

- [Suggest removal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52799) of reference to [remote](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote) in tag [drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drush) (with suggested edit comment = Remove reference to tag 'remote' which got deleted recently).
- [Suggest removal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52799) of reference to [aliases](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliases) in tag [drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drush) (with suggested edit comment = Remove reference to tag 'aliases' which got deleted recently).

I was lucky, these 2 extra edits got accepted. That were 2+2 easy points I gained, but maybe that's because I hinted the reviewers about that orphaned tag reference I suggested to be resolved? But before submitting these 2 extra edits, I actually doubted if they were not going to be clasified as "too minor, this user is trying to just gain some points by cutting an obviously related set of edits in multiple wiki edit iterations" (... and hence 2 more rejected edits!). Note: the real reason, for myself at least, why I did so in 2 iterations is because when I submitted the first wiki edit suggestion, I had not yet noticed that the 2nd tag had been deleted also ...