# Why am I temporarily banned from suggesting edits?

Tags: support, editing

I see the message, "You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits", when I try to suggest typo fixes I've seen. I presume this is because of the series of rejected edits I've made to the tag wiki. Is this true? Also, how long does this ban stay in place?

Comment: Congratulations in pushing the edit button too much! I'm in the same boat, though not on Drupal Answers though. Don't worry, just be patient (between 1 to 7 days?). In my case I suffer the same problem on the overall meta site ... again. I'm confident that reviewers like kiamialuno and free radical have good intentions (ie reasons to "so now and then" reject suggested edits), just consider it as constructive critique. While your "timeout" lasts, how about we organize some chatroom party (or just head over to any other SE site). Like "New User Experience" room? Do NOT give up, ok?

Comment: I just created http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22624/new-user-experience-for-drupal-answers ... I have no experience with chat rooms on SE at this moment. Want to join there? Of course: same invitation for anybody else ...

Comment: Consider changing the title of this question to something like "Am I temporarely banned because of my series of rejected edits, and if so for how long?"

Comment: @Pierre No worries or frustrations. This isn't the first time I've been on a community-editable site. If you're not breaking things you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I figured out the tour badge pretty quick.  I semi-scripted a way to login with my SE login, navigate to /tour, & scroll to the bottom for each SE site that have knowledge/interest in.

Comment: talking about scripting: http://stackapps.com/ is an interesting place to investigate ... while being banned (and receiving upvotes on Drupal Answers) ... Just in case you get bored while being banned: are you familiar with the distribution https://www.drupal.org/project/arrayshift? Something interested happened over there (cfr its issue queue for details) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are banned from suggesting edits when they get their suggested edits rejected. In your case, the suggested edits were for tag wikis, and two of them were automatically rejected because the tag the wiki was referring was deleted or merged. The same applies to other suggested edits, if you still don't have the privilege for editing every post.

The standard ban lasts seven days. After that, the ban is removed, but it will be applied again the next time you get most of your recently suggested edits rejected.

Answer (score 1):

That ban is for having too many rejected edits.  Usually, you get these from trying to edit the tag wiki, as tag wiki edits gets (as a rule) far more rejections than other edits.

The ban will be automatically lifted in a week.

As I say in a comment to [this question](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/how-can-i-use-propose-tag-wiki-without-taking-the-risk-of-a-rejected-edit): Suggesting tag wiki edits is dangerous. They often get rejected, and sometimes for (at least to me) non-obvious reasons.  If you want to keep your editing privileges, it is probably best to stay away from the tag wiki.

Answer (score -3):

Yes I agree with [Free Radical](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12076/free-radical) about such edits being dangerous (so +1 for it) ... But "Worse then not succeeding ... is to not have tried". And even if you fail, keep trying, just never give up. At best be a bit patient to be allowed again. I just discovered that "my" Temporary Ban on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (= no edit suggestions of questions or tags allowed) was lifted again, after a 7 days timeout, so my "test environment" for 
[Trying to improve a tag wiki while blocked causes incorrect 'This post has been deleted'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251550/trying-to-improve-a-tag-wiki-while-blocked-tells-you-the-post-is-deleted) no longer works "for me". Maybe [Shawn Conn](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/45675/shawn-conn) is willing to verify the same issue using "Drupal Answers" as the test environment now (and somehow confirm my suggested answer over there)?

Also funny (I think): I was banned for 7 days, and without doing anything (I couldn't because of the ban ...), my reputation went back up to only 1 below my maximum so far. My points went down quite a bit, because of 1 question + related answer there that got downvoted heavily (damage: -19-6 = -25 ...). I honestly don't care about what SE calls "reputation" (ie "points"), that is not why I contribute to any SE site (trust me).

I'm considering yet another approach over there to get my "editor stats" balance over there in "better" shape again. Right now the balance is "**33** edit suggestions approved, and **24** edit suggestions rejected". Just in case anybody want to "judge" that ratio: make sure to carefully analyse the actual rejection details ... Maybe also consider some App (on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/)) to help you on it, but don't get burned like in the [question with my suggested edit](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/2752) for it. Note: 'all' (=1) my suggested edits over there are approved, with a 0% rejection rate ...).

Comment: Its not a huge deal. I understand why it is in place, to prevent spamming. Furthermore, the ban is just editing tag wiki stuff, I can still do Q&A which is the core activity on here.

Comment: This is a little beyond the scope of this thread, but another thing that might be helpful inside SE's gamification system is to give people "quests", some relatively-tedious maintenance task that shows off some knowledge and also helps improves the site. That's how I looked at editing the tag wiki; I took my experience as a Wikipedia and thought "hey, I can help by filling out some stubs!"

Comment: Great comments ... seems like we have similar goals / attitudes! Keep on the good work!

Comment: Some of his edits was rejected due to lack of usage guidance or copied content as far as I remember. "Never give up" is bad advice for such cases. If anything, he should give up until he knows what was seen as wrong and is convinced he can do better. At least these two reasons are pretty clear and objective.

Comment: @Mołot thanks for the comment, that's another way of looking at it. "Now" (about 4 months later) I better understand how most of the things on Drupal.SE work. But still I keep "struggling" with some of the attitudes, procedures, etc. But hey, think of all the amazing things around here, and how we all can learn about Drupal from each other, no?